# Use a UIView as the background of a UIButton?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have a UIButton.  Rather than giving it a background Image, I want to use a custom UIView object as the background.  I realize I could do this by rendering the UIView into an image, then using that.  But is there a better way?

I've looked at playing with the Button's view tree, but that seems to have undesirable side effects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve the same, I usually do this:

Add subview to the parentView

Add a UIButton with clearColor to the parentView, with the same frame as the subview.

You can achieve the same by creating a custom UIView class that has this view and button as its properties.

Comment: Can you get showsTouchWhenHighlighted to work this way?

Comment: glad it helped. unless you want to convenience of using UIButton features, you can also use tap gesture recognizer as suggested by @Logan.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a UIView as a button, you should just add a tap gesture recognizer to the UIView and use that.  Is there something specific you're looking for?